# C# search using a LINQ query with child records

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a Person and PersonType object where a Person has one to many PersonTypes. A PersonType can be Accountant, Consultant etc.

Person table has the following columns: 
'firstname' | 'lastname' | 'email' | 'phonenumber'

PersonType table has the following columns:
'name' | 'description'

I've created a search mechanism using LINQ in C# but the problem is that I get a wrong result due to an issue with a LINQ constraint. Suppose we have two Person records where the first record is a Consultant and the other record is Consultant and Accountant meaning it has to child objects.

Note. My search is case insensitive.

Suppose my search text is 'co'. Then I don't want the result to be 3 records. Now it returns the first person and two instances of the second person due to two matches of 'co' for Accountant and Consultant for the second Person.

Of course I can go through the result and filter out duplicates but it would be nice to have it one query.

Many thanks for your input.

Here is the Linq:

```
private IList<PersonViewModel> SearchAll(string searchCriteria)
{
   var result = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Persons"] as IList<PersonViewModel>;

    if (result != null)
    {
        var v = (from a in result
                 from b in a.PersonTypes
                    where
                            a.FirstName.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria) ||
                            a.LastName.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria) ||
                            a.Email.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria) ||
                            a.PhoneNumber.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria) ||
                            b.Name.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)
                 select a);

        return v.ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The morning coffee kicked in. I just added a Distinct() statement in the end of the expression. Done and dusted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One little strategy may be very helpful in problems with queries and search conditions:

**Only query the entities you need and do nothing but `where`.**

You need `PersonViewModel`s. By joining in `PersonTypes` (`from - from` is a `GroupJoin`) also `PersonTypes` become accessible to the end result. So if you only query the entities you need, there should be one, and only one, `from`:

```
var v = from a in result
```

Now what should the `where` be? The conditions for `PersonViewModel` are clear, but what about `PersonTypes`? Loosely defined in plain language, *where at least one of their `PersonTypes` contains "co"*. In LINQ that amounts to:

```
var v = from a in result
    where a.FirstName.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)
       || a.LastName.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)
       || a.Email.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)
       || a.PhoneNumber.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)
       || a.PersonTypes.Any(pt => pt.Name.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria));
```

Now you don't need `Distinct` because there's no `join` that duplicates results.

Answer (score 1):

you can get result as following

```
var v=result?.Where(p=>p.PersonTypes.Select(t=>t.Name).Contains(searchCriteria)    ||
                            p.FirstName.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)   ||
                            p.LastName.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)    ||
                            p.Email.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria)       ||
                            p.PhoneNumber.CaseInsensitiveContains(searchCriteria) ||)?.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Salam 
i think you can do it like that

```
v.GroupBy(person => person.id)
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```